# Bash's "set -v" doesn't echo commands within curly braces to stdout

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have the following test script:

```
# test.bash
#----------
{

   set -v # Echoes the following 3 parameters
   DELAY_MS=2000
   SCALING=false
   VERBOSE=false
   set +v

   echo TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST

} 2>&1 | tee test.bash.out
```

It sets 3 variables and echos a `TEST` line of output.  Because of the `set -v`, I expect the 3 variables settings to be mirrored to *stdout* and `tee`'d to `test.bash.out`.  However, they show up in neither the Bash console or `test.bash.out`.

Why would they not show up?

Is there a simple way to have the variables show up in *stdout*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set -v` (short for `set -o verbose`) prints source lines *as they're read*, and before the shell can execute anything within the braces, it has to read it all to figure out if there's a redirection or pipe or `&`, etc at the end. (And to check if there's the matching `}` somewhere, though you could argue that's not exactly necessary.)

If you want to see what the shell *executes*, use `set -x` (or `set -o xtrace`) instead.